# Should we either use PHP websocket or Node.js? Or are they totally different things?

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

I'm a newbie in the realm of sockets and NODE.js. I apologize if it seems so obvious.
I've recently read so many article about NODE.js, but today stumbled upon [Ratchet websocket](http://socketo.me/). a php component library that use can use to build chat applications and other thing. Is there any difference between them? When should we use node or the other? Are they similar or totally different things? Could someone shed some light on the subject please I'm in dark now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both capable of running web socket servers.  It is purely preference of what you want to work with on your server side, javascript or PHP.

Comment: Haven't you seen any performance issue with the PHP one i.e. Ratchet?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ratchet itself.  I've written a PHP socket server for my own proprietary purporses.  I would prefer PHP for this sort of thing since, PHP is made to be a server side language and has far more time in the wild as a server side language than javascript has.